# Repeat background image as header

Tags: html, css, image

Trying to get my image to repeat on the x-axis along the top of my webpage. The image appears but doesn't repeat.

HTML:

```
<div id='head'><img src='img/header.jpg'></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #head img {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: `#head { background-image : url('img/header.jpg'); }`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've used the `<img>` tags to put an image on your webpage. But what you wantto do is set the background like so:

CSS:

```
#head {
    background-image:url('img/header.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='head'></div>
```

Comment: #head img or only #head?

Comment: it should be only #head as you need only background image to your head div and img tag will be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I forgot to delete it :p.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted out. You can delete the question, post your own answer, or accept this answer by clicking on the empty check mark at the left.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is displaying an image within a div.

If you want to have your image as a background you need to set it in the css file like :

```
#head {
    background-image:url('img/header.jpg');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

and then remove the img balise from your html code :

```
<div id='head'>&nbsp;</div>
```

stands for non-breakable space to be sure you have a content in your balise.

FoW

EDIT: Tom was faster than me

EDIT: made css work :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/peNNy/).

HTML:

```
 <div id='head'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#head {
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image:url("http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRueEELruucpzBbsfBcn_JPGG338iDtWWoJPYo3o9AvbKty37edzg");
}
```

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code is doing:

The img tag is inserting a single image (header.jpg) into the code.
Your css styling is telling the code to repeat any css-assigned background image along the x-axis, inside the space provided by the img tag.

All that to say: assign the style directly to the head id and add header.jpg as a background-image to the style, and it'll work fine.
Try the below as an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.kitty 
{
background-image: url('http://images5.fanpop.com/image/photos/26000000/Nyan-Cat-Gif-   nyan-cat-26044255-500-375.gif');
height:400px;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-color:#cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="kitty">Hello World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to repeat your image , apply image in div's background using css
HTML :

```
<div class="head">
&nbsp; &nbsp;
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
.head{
 background:url("/images/pulpit.jpg") ;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 position:absolute;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;

 }
</style>
```